# wordpress theme css and js files are not loading on live

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, plugins

I am working on wordpress website when I see my site after admin login all is working fine. but when I check the site on live the hole layout is broken
can anyone tell me how to fix it
Thank in advance. 
Site url: https://www.dfhcompany.com/air-conditioners/

Comment: check. htaccess file is there or not you can also try to change permalinks to post and refresh page and change back to custom again

Comment: You have `Uncaught TypeError: isMobile is not a function` in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337).

Comment: yes I have seen this error on other site also but this is coming from library min.js cant edit that

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be some error in JS "Uncaught TypeError: isMobile is not a function". Also, You can check the file permission. Might be its a file permission issue.

Comment: this is not the cause, if this has been reason then the home page also should be distracted.